# JavaScript libraries that handle would highlight the edge of scroll container where there is content

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I am lacking of a better term to describe this UX.  It is basically a content container that is scrollable.  Depending on the scrolling position, the top or bottom edge of container would light up (or change style) to indicate there is content at either of the direction.  For example, when you go to Yahoo.com, and scroll down a little, the top edge of the scrollable section would turn purple, indicating there is content at the top that's outside of the viewport.  (See image below)

I wonder if there is already some well known script library that can achieve this so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

[image: Yahoo.com]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly custom concept, but you can see how to get started by looking at the way Bootstrap's Affix method works: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix

Essentially you will need to have a scroll event listener which tracks what the position is that a user is scrolled on a container. When the scroll position reaches certain breakpoints, the listener function will trigger CSS classes which may do a variety of things.